# Restoring deleted partitions/files

Tags: 12.10, data-recovery, ntfs, delete, drive

I had Windows 7 installed on my computer and four partitions, namely, C (where Windows was installed), D, E, and F. I decided to install Ubuntu and ended up deleting all my partitions, but one with Ubuntu installed.

Is there any way I can get my files back?

Comment: Let this be a lesson: if it is important why did you not create a backup before doing something this drastic? Heck, why do you not regularly create a backup even when not doing things this drastic?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EncqYP1ijFg using [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Results may vary based on expertise so it might be a good idea to let someone do this that knows what to do (any slight error will ruin your chances of getting it back). 
I suggest to ***not*** touch the partitions and do this from another machine or a live CD.

---

Helpful but technical resource:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: ok thnx i will try this